# Count com valor nulo retornar zero

Tags: sql, count

Fiz um insert em uma tabela e agora preciso fazer um select nessa tabela fazendo um count em uma determinada coluna.

A questão é que essa coluna (que dei o nome de pedido) tem valor nulo para algumas situações e quando faço o count, gostaria que fosse indicado 0 (zero) para essas situações (atualmente está retornando 1) e para as colunas que tem valor diferente de zero, fazer o count normalmente.

Alguém pode me ajudar , por gentileza, a montar um comando para isso ? será que é possível retornar as informações dessa forma ?

```
select 0,
a.seqpessoa,
a.nomerazao,
a.cidade,
a.uf,
a.bairro,
a.fone,
a.dtaultfat,
a.datref,
a.equipe,
count (a.pedido) as pedido
from PAS_CLI_CAD_EQUIPE_PEDIDO a
group by a.seqpessoa,
a.nomerazao,
a.cidade,
a.uf,
a.bairro,
a.fone,
a.dtaultfat,
a.datref,
a.equipe;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar uma combinação de soma com condicional para somar zero ou um conforme o caso.

Exemplo compatível com diversas bases:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN a.pedido IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS total
```

Exemplo para MySQL:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(a.pedido IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS total
```

Comment: Muito Obrigada!!  Deu certo!!!

Answer (score 1):

Se você usa postgres 9.4+, use o comando FILTER (Veja a doc [aqui](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html)). Funciona para qualquer função de agregação. Veja:

```
select 0,
a.seqpessoa,
a.nomerazao,
a.cidade,
a.uf,
a.bairro,
a.fone,
a.dtaultfat,
a.datref,
a.equipe,
count (a.pedido) FILTER (WHERE a.pedido IS NOT NULL)as pedido
from PAS_CLI_CAD_EQUIPE_PEDIDO a
group by a.seqpessoa,
a.nomerazao,
a.cidade,
a.uf,
a.bairro,
a.fone,
a.dtaultfat,
a.datref,
a.equipe;
```

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda Cristiano!

Comment: De nada. Porém, a resposta do @bfavaretto é mais universal e atende todos os bancos de dados, por usar o padrão SQL.